# Rspec: setting a controller attribute set to my mock object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I've got a controller test that I'm trying to work through. Basically the controller looks like this:

```
before_filter :set_up_foo

def set_up_foo
  ...
  @foo = SomeObject.create(params[:some_object_attributes])
  ...
end

def some_action
  # reference @foo
  if @foo.nil?
    ...
  else
    # this is what I want to test
    ...
  end
end
```

I don't want to test the innards of the else block, not the before filter. In my case there are a TON of models objects I'd have to mock in order to actually execute the before filter. I have another test for that. I want to make sure the 'side effect' of the before filter is done...in this case that @foo gets initialized to a mock version of it.

Basically I want to do:

```
controller.foo = mock_foo_object
```

but this doesn't work. I also tried:

```
controller.stub!(:foo).and_return(mock_foo_object)
```

and though I expected (haha) this to work, it didn't. The only real feedback I get is that the @foo object is never set and as a result we got the if, not the else condition.

any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

So I found this solution: Instead of mocking the accessor, I can pass a block into the stub on the method that has the side effect, to DO that side effect:

```
controller.stub!(:set_up_foo) { controller.set_instance_variable(:@foo, @mock_foo_object) }
```

This has the effect of making sure the one side effect I care about actually happens. I tried this and it worked like a charm.